# creating an Dynamic xAxis label in MPAndroidChart library

Tags: java, android, retrofit2, bar-chart

creating a Dynamic xAxis label in MPAndroidChart library.

I use group bar Chart.
I set static label :

```
final String[] weakArea = {"Physical Database Design", "Object-Oriented Database","data base"};

     xAxis.setValueFormatter(new IndexAxisValueFormatter(weakArea));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 public ArrayList<String> getweakAreaCount() {

        ArrayList<String> label = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < weakAreaList.size(); i++)
            label.add(weakAreaList.get(i).getTopicNm());
        return label;
    }

xAxis.setValueFormatter(new IndexAxisValueFormatter(getweakAreaCount));
```